# StringManager.getManager() usage

Tags: glassfish

I need help with the usage of com.sun.enterprise.util.i18n.StringManager (common-util.jar version 3.x). I haven't found how can I use the method

getManager(String packageName, ClassLoader classLoader)

what I don't how to instance the ClassLoader object to use the method (the older version of this method only had the String argument)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you do

```
 StringManager.getManager(getClass().getPackage().getName(), getClass().getClassLoader());
```

or you load your bundle directly

```
 StringManager.getManager(ResourceBundle.getBundle("bundle.properties"));
```